# How to retrieve current user data using parse sdk in android?

Tags: android, parse-platform

The goal is : after a user has been logged in , the next activity should display his list of courses. 
There is a table of courses in Parse's cloud, but how can I retrieve the correct courses (current user's courses) ? 
I've thought of 2 approaches : 
1. using getCurrentUser method - but what if there are more than one user in the cache ?
2. save for each course the userName that saved it , and then query for that userName - but how should I know that the currentUser method will return the correct user ?

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. using getCurrentUser method - but what if there are more than one user in the cache ?

There's always one currently logged in user and `ParseUser.getCurrentUser()` will get it. Well, unless there is *no* logged in user.

> but how should I know that the currentUser method will return the correct user

As above. I don't get what you're confused about.

> There is a table of courses in Parse's cloud, but how can I retrieve the correct courses (current user's courses)

and

> save for each course the userName that saved it , and then query for that userName - but how should I know that the currentUser method will return the correct user ?

I can think of two approaches here. There may be more. Up to you what you decide to use.

So you have the `_User` table and the `Course` table. You can do one of the following:

1. Add a `courses` array to each `_User` and for each `_User`, store their list of courses there. It should be a list of `objectId`s, so basically you'll have the ID's of all the courses that `_User` is registered for. Each Parse object has a limited size in the database so you should use it if you are sure you won't need big amounts of data for each user. If you want to retrieve this, query the `_User` table by the id of the user and fetch the list of courses.
2. The "relational" approach: add an `UserCourse` table that has a `userId` and a `courseId` column. Every time you want to add a course for a particular user, you add a new entry in here that holds the id of that user and the id o the course. Similarly to the above, have a query that fetches all the stuff from `UserCourse` by `userId`. Note that in this case you'll also need to make sure your query fetches the data from `_User` and `Course`. Otherwise you'll just end up with `UserCourse` entries, which merely store ID's.

Comment: I guess I don't understand how ParseUser.getCurrentUser() works. If 2 different users login from the same device , so the cache has the data of the last one who logged in ?

Comment: It's not the last user, but the currently logged in user. So if user A logs in, logs out, and user B logs in, then user B is returned. If user B then logs out, then `null` is returned. And if user A now logs in, then user A is returned. And so on.

Comment: thanks, by the way , regarding to your first approach , how do I save an array as a value in ParseObject ?

Comment: @user704023 By using the `ParseObject.add()` method: https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#add%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29